# Storing/ Getting children from Parent Class

Tags: java, arraylist

I have 2 Classes, Book and Journal which both extend the Reference class. 
I originally stored them into separate ArrayLists but now am required to store them all into a Reference ArrayList.

I used the original 2 arraylists to store the users reference and then when they searched for it, it would search both arrays to find it.

My question is how do I use the functions from the book and journal classes? Or the overridden functions.

Comment: You should be able to store both `Book` and `Journal` objects in a `List<Reference>` if they both extend `Reference`. If they both override functions from `Reference`, you can call those methods on either, and it will call the overriden method for each one. If you want to use functions specifically from `Book` or `Journal`, you'll have to cast it appropriately.

Comment: @JackmeriusTacktheritrix but book has certain strings that are unique to it's class and journal does as well so would those string survive being put into the list initially?

Comment: They will still "survive". It might help if you post some code that you're concerned about accessing.

Answer (score 0):

When iterating over your `List<Reference>`, you can check to see if it is a `Book` or a `Journal`, then call methods specific to `Book` and `Journal`:

```
for (Reference ref : list) {
    if (ref instanceof Book) {
        ((Book) ref).bookMethod();
    } else if (ref instanceof Journal) {
        ((Journal) ref).journalMethod();
    }
}
```

You don't need to use `instanceof` or cast to `Book/Journal` if you're calling methods from `Reference` that may or may not be overriden:

```
for (Reference ref : list) {
   ref.doSomething();
}
```

If `Book` and `Journal` both override `doSomething()`, then it will execute the `Book/Journal` specific implemenation, otherwise it will use the `Reference` implementation.